# On Ubuntu, with nmcli, how to properly enter a valid password for wifi connection with 802-1x, without plaintext password saving

Tags: ubuntu, password, networkmanager, nmcli, 802.1x

In my company, a Wi-Fi access point with 802-1.x authentication has been setup.
I can successfully connect to the access point with the `nmcli` command line like this
`nmcli device wifi connect "Company Wi-Fi"`,
provided I set it up before with `nm-connection-editor`, where I enter my password.

However, this stores the password in plaintext under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, which I don't like.

Fortunately, I found that there is an option `password-flags=2` that prevents such plaintext storing, which is a good idea. Combined with `nmcli --ask device wifi connect "Company Wi-Fi"`, everything seems to be there for success, however when answering with my (good) password, I receive this error message :
`Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.`

(I run all these commands as `sudo` , btw)

Any ideas ?